# repeated 'values' tag in map reduce

Tags: python, mongodb, mapreduce

I am trying to aggregate business ratings for users into one collection using map reduce.

```
mapper = Code("""
              function(){
              var userID = this.user_id;
              var business = this.business_id;
              var rating = this.stars;

              emit(userId, {business_id: business, stars: rating});
              """)

reducer = Code("""
              function(key, values){
              var results = new Object();
              results.values = values;
              return results;
```

I would expect to get 
    {u'_id': u'--65q1FpAL_UQtVZ2PTGew', u'value': {business: rating}, {business: rating}}

but what I'm getting is 
    {u'_id': u'--65q1FpAL_UQtVZ2PTGew', u'value': [u'values':[[u'values':[ u'values': [{business: rating}, {business: rating}...

how can I remove all of the extra 'values' tags from my output?

Comment: I just tried what you posted, but couldn't duplicate your results. What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operator-group/) instead? It's generally more efficient than mapReduce, and seems to be a better fit for your application. For example, an aggregation solution to your issue would be:

```
db.coll.aggregate({ $group: { _id: "$user_id", 
                    values: { $push: { business_id: "$business_id", 
                                       stars: "$stars" }}}});
```

You could then save the result to a new collection, or whatever else you like.